# Python pandas swap columns values with split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
TTL1   TTL2   TTL3   TTL4   TTL5
val1   val2   val3   val4   some value
val1   val2   val3   val4   
val1   val2   val3   val4   some more value
val1   val2   val3   val4   some value
val1          val3          val2 val4
val1   val2   val3   val4   some value
```

**Explnation:**
sometimes the values of `TTL2` and `TTL4` jumps to TTL5.
so what I want to do, is to check if `TTL2` and `TTL4` are empty, and if so, go to `TTL5`, split it by (space) and put each value in the correct column.

though I am facing some troubles with that...

any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that there is a much more efficient way of doing this (using one of `pandas` vectorized methods), but this is what I got so far. It should have a reasonable runtime as long as your dataframe is not too big.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'TTL2': ['a', None], 'TTL4': ['b', None], 'TTL5': [None, 'a b']})

print(df)

#     TTL2  TTL4  TTL5
#  0     a     b  None
#  1  None  None   a b

for row in df.iterrows():
    index = row[0]
    ttl2_val = row[1].TTL2
    ttl4_val = row[1].TTL4
    if not ttl2_val and not ttl4_val:
        df.ix[index, 'TTL2'], df.ix[index, 'TTL4'] = row[1].TTL5.split()

print(df)

#      TTL2 TTL4  TTL5
#    0    a    b  None
#    1    a    b   a b
```

Comment: Why do you hate hats but? :P

Comment: @MYGz I find hats to be uncomfortable